# Polymer 1.0 Extending Elements - paper-dialog with custom element

Tags: polymer

I am am trying to create a custom element that plays a youtube video in `paper-dialog`. So `videoPlayer = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('video-player');` inherits/has access to that `paper-dialog`s `open` method, I am trying to extend my custom element. It isn't working, but hopefully I am on the right track and someone can show me correctly.

I am using `Polymer 1.0`, but I only have https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements to go by for extending elements.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-youtube/google-youtube.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="video-player">
  <template>
      <div class="layout horizontal">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>
          <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
        </paper-button>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
        <google-youtube style="height: 100%;"
          video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
          rel="1"
          start="5"
          playsinline="0"
          controls="2"
          showinfo="0"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          autoplay="1">
        </google-youtube>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "video-player"
    });
  </script>
```

```
<paper-dialog name="video-player" extends="video-player">
  <template>
    <shadow></shadow>
  </template>
  <script>
     Polymer();
  </script>
</paper-dialog>
```

---

```
<video-player></video-player>
```

Comment: Extending non-native elements is currently not a feature in 1.0

Comment: How could I reverse it and extend `paper-dialog` and customize it to make it like a custom element?

Comment: as @miyamoto said, you can't extend non-native elements so any Polymer element you are using or create cannot be extending. You can only extend native HTML elements such as `input`, `td`, `li` etc. This may be possible in a future version.

Comment: The functionality you're looking for has been moved to 'behaviors'. Take a look here, https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input and you'll see that paper-input uses 3 different behaviors. To 'extend' paper-input, you basically just need to include those same behaviors in your element.

Comment: This is for `paper-dialog`, not `paper-input`. I tried to import the bevaior on just a custom element, but it was not the solution for me. I need the open method of `paper-dialog` that is actually being used, so inheriting that method would no link it to a particular instance.

Comment: @BenThomas ...oh I thought native meant native Polymer elements. +1 for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned in the comments, you can't *yet* extend custom elements, so the existing pattern (or at least the one I use) is to make use of behaviors wherever possible and wrappers wherever not.

e.g.

```
<dom-module id="popup-video-player">
  <template>
    <video-player></video-player>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'popup-video-player',
      behaviors: [Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior],
      ...
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now you can use `<popup-video-player>` just like a `paper-dialog`.

I know it stinks because if `video-player` has a bunch of properties that you want access to, you have to copy them in the `popup-video-player` element's API, which is not exactly DRY.

If you look at the [`paper-input` source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html), you'll see them doing the same thing. It's obvious that they want to extend `iron-input`, but they can't so you get things like this:

```
  <input is="iron-input" id="input"
    aria-labelledby$="[[_ariaLabelledBy]]"
    aria-describedby$="[[_ariaDescribedBy]]"
    disabled$="[[disabled]]"
    title$="[[title]]"
    ... >
```

As a side note, you could always hook into the `<video-player>`s "properties" property and make the API additions programatically.

maybe something like this would work: (untested!)

```
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: (function () {
    var prop = {
      //special properties specific to the pop up version of video-player
      //..obviously be careful to avoid name space conflicts.
    };
    var video_player = document.createElement('video-player');
    video_player.properties.keys().forEach( function(key) {
      props[key] = video_player[key];
    });
    return props;
  }()),

});
```